# Web API that uses a default connection string to authenticate and an external database to get data

Tags: .net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I have a Solution that has an MVC architectural structure and a WEB Api. The web page connects to the WEB Api to first login and get a token (by using a local DB). Once it has the token, the website connects to it again as to get a Product. The method on the Web API is displayed below:

```
public IEnumerable<string> Get(int id)
{
    try
    {
        Commonlayer.Views.ProductView pv = new ProductRepository().GetProductV(id);
        return new string[] { pv.Description, pv.Email, pv.ImageLink, pv.Name, pv.Price.ToString() };
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        return new string[] { "1", "2", "3"};
    }
}
```

What this does is that it connects to my Data Access Layer which is responsibly for getting a Product from the SQL Database. However this keeps failing, probably because I cannot connect to the DB properly. I tried to add a connection string other than my current local DB string in the WEB API Config, however that results in an error when it tries to login (possibly because it is confused on which connection string to use?).

This is the default connection string:

```
    <connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-WebAPI.mdf;Initial Catalog=aspnet-WebAPI;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
      </connectionStrings>
```

At this point I have no idea what to do, any pointers would be great.

Comment: What medium are you using to connect to the DB?

Comment: The Local DB was create automatically and the external DB is connected to by using an Entity Model.

Answer (score 0):

I found out the answer. I needed two connection strings in my WEB API, One for the local db and one for the external. However I was writing the connection strings in different manners, solved now.